# How can i get the user's current voice channel ID?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to get the channel ID that a certain user, target from a command is connect and then use it to move to a channel

This is my current test code:

```
@client.command(aliases=['teste'])
async def test(ctx, target: discord.Member): 
    channel_return = (target.voice)
    await ctx.send (channel_return['VoiceChannel id'])
```

it returns on the discord text chat the value:
`<VoiceState self_mute=True self_deaf=False self_stream=False suppress=False requested_to_speak_at=None channel=<VoiceChannel id=734512711748157471 name=':eyes: :regional_indicator_s: :regional_indicator_a: :regional_indicator_l: :regional_indicator_a:' rtc_region=<VoiceRegion.us_central: 'us-central'> position=4 bitrate=64000 user_limit=0 category_id=703115313884954624>>`

which have the channel_id, but i can't acess without getting the error:

`TypeError: 'VoiceState' object is not subscriptable`

How can i access the value of VoiceChannel id from a target user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.command(aliases=['teste'])
async def test(ctx, target: discord.Member):
    if target.voice:
        channel_return = target.voice.channel
    else:
        return
```

member.voice returns the voice_state of the member which basically means is current voice status (channel, speaking [ect](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.VoiceState))
what I have done was checking if he is actually in a voice because if he isn't voice is going to return None and then you wouldn't be able to access the channel because none doesn't have a channel attribute.
you've to take the channel like it is a dict but what you saw was an object so all of the values there were attributes or properties that the voice_state object had

Comment: Big thanks man!

i could store the channel ID by using: 

```channel_return = client.get_channel(member.voice.channel.id) ```

so now i can move a user over the voice channels and then move he back into the original channel!